# Geting wrong results from the hibernate query

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 records in mysql database and these are,

```
mysql> select name,dob,gender,profession,relationship,dependent from family;
+------+------------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| name | dob        | gender | profession | relationship | dependent |
+------+------------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| XYZ  | 1991-02-10 | MALE   | DEVELOPER  | BROTHER      | TRUE      |
| ABC  | 1991-02-10 | FEMALE | DEVELOPER  | SISTER       | TRUE      |
| DEF  | 1991-02-10 | FEMALE | DEVELOPER  | SISTER       | TRUE      |
+------+------------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when i trying to display these records in my jsp page, the below code is always displaying the first record only in three times,

```
 Family fa=null;
 List members = session.createQuery("FROM Family").list();
 for (Iterator iterator = members.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){ 
     fa= (Family) iterator.next();
     f[i]=new Family(
                fa.getname(),
                 fa.getdob(),
                    fa.getgender(),
                     fa.getprofession(),
                     fa.getrelationship(),
                     fa.getdependent()
             );
     f[i].setname(fa.getname()); 
     System.out.println(f[i].getname());
     i++;
    fa=null;
 }
 HttpSession ses=request.getSession();
 ses.setAttribute("f",f);
 ses.setAttribute("i", String.valueOf(i));
```

when i ran this code i am getting the following output

```
 XYZ
 XYZ
 XYZ
```

please tell me what i have been wrong with this code.

here i am showing the 'family.java' code

```
 package com.lms.model;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class Family extends ActionForm
{
int id;
String employee_no;
String name;
String nominee;
String dob;
int age;
String nationality;
String blood_group;
String gender;
String profession;
String relationship;
String dependent;
String medi_claim;
String medi_history;
public Family(){}
public Family(
        String name,
        String dob,
        String gender,
        String profession,
        String relationship,
        String dependent){
    this.name=name;
    this.dob=dob;
    this.gender=gender;
    this.profession=profession;
    this.relationship=relationship;
    this.dependent=dependent;
}
public String getemployee_no()
{
    return employee_no;
}
public void setemployee_no(String str)
{
    employee_no=str;
}
public int getid()
{
    return id;
}
public void setid(int str)
{
    id=str;
}
public String getname()
{
    return name;
}
public void setname(String str)
{
    name=str;
}
public String getnominee()
{
    return nominee;
}
public void setnominee(String str)
{
    nominee=str;
}public String getdob()
{
    return dob;
}
public void setdob(String str)
{
    dob=str;
}public int getage()
{
    return age;
}
public void setage(int str)
{
    age=str;
}public String getnationality()
{
    return nationality;
}
public void setnationality(String str)
{
    nationality=str;
}
public String getblood_group()
{
    return blood_group;
}
public void setblood_group(String str)
{
    blood_group=str;
}public String getgender()
{
    return gender;
}
public void setgender(String str)
{
    gender=str;
}public String getprofession()
{
    return profession;
}
public void setprofession(String str)
{
    profession=str;
}public String getrelationship()
{
    return relationship;
}
public void setrelationship(String str)
{
    relationship=str;
}public String getdependent()
{
    return dependent;
}
public void setdependent(String str)
{
    dependent=str;
}public String getmedi_claim()
{
    return medi_claim;
}
public void setmedi_claim(String str)
{
    medi_claim=str;
}public String getmedi_history()
{
    return medi_history;
}
public void setmedi_history(String str)
{
    medi_history=str;
}
 }
```

jsp code is

```
          <%
    HttpSession ss=request.getSession();
    int i=Integer.parseInt(ss.getAttribute("i").toString());
    Family f[]=(Family[])(ss.getAttribute("f"));
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=f[j].getname()%></td>
        <td><%=f[j].getdob()%></td>
        <td><%=f[j].getgender()%></td>
        <td><%=f[j].getprofession()%></td>
        <td><%=f[j].getrelationship()%></td>
        <td><%=f[j].getdependent()%></td>
        <td>edit</td>
        <td>delete</td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
```

mapping code for only family pojo is:

```
    <class name="com.lms.model.Family" table="family">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the details of employee family. 
     </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
    <property name="employee_no" column="empno" type="string"  />
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"  />
    <property name="nominee" column="nominated" type="string"  />
    <property name="dob" column="dob" type="string"  />
    <property name="age" column="age" type="int"  />
    <property name="nationality" column="nationality" type="string"  />
    <property name="blood_group" column="blood_group" type="string"  />
    <property name="gender" column="gender" type="string"  />
    <property name="profession" column="profession" type="string"  />
    <property name="relationship" column="relationship" type="string"  />
    <property name="dependent" column="dependent" type="string"  />
    <property name="medi_claim" column="medi_claim" type="string"  />
    <property name="medi_history" column="medi_history" type="string"  />
    </class>
```

Comment: please check the sql that generated by hql, you will get the solution.

Comment: i changed the query and adjusted,but i am getting the same.

Comment: Check the query generated by hibernate and directly run it over DB to make sure you are getting correct records. Next the Java code looks good, so show the JSP code which you are using to display the data to user. Finally what is f[]?

Comment: i checked the query and it is correct, and i had updated and showed the jsp code as well as family.java code

Comment: you are working with 'for' loop you should have to try 'foreach' loop. List of member that comes from query result is list of Family so you can iterate with foreach loop .

Comment: foreach is identical to for loop, I think it might not change the results.

Comment: Which Hibernate Version are you using? The `Family`object you've posted seems not to be the Hibernate Entity `Family` it has a lot more fields like `age` and no annotation that these Fields are not mapped to any column. So either how does your hibernate mapping look like or how does the Entity object look like?

Comment: i am using hibernate4.3.6, i had updated the question and shown the mapping file. please view this update in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the result.
In the code i forget to save the id in the session and i changed the code like this, when i had added below code

```
   Family fm = new Family(f.getname(),f.getnominee(),f.getdob(),f.getage (),f.getnationality(), f.getblood_group(),f.getgender(),f.getprofession(),f.getrelationship(), f.getdependent(),f.getmedi_claim(),f.getmedi_history());
   fmID = (Integer) session.save(fm);
 List members = session.createQuery("FROM Family").list();
 for (Iterator iterator = members.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){ 
     fa= (Family) iterator.next();
     System.out.println(fa.getname());
     f[i]=fa;
     i++;
 }
```

I got the results.
Thank you so much friends for your guidance.